# How to spawn Python2.5 process through Apache and return immediately under Windows

Tags: python, apache2, subprocess

I have two Python scripts, one launches the other with subprocess

invoke.py:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'long.py'])
print "Content-Type: text/plain\n"
print "invoked (%d)" % (p.pid)
```

longtime.py:

```
import time
import os
print "start (%d)" %(os.getpid())
time.sleep(10)
print "end (%d)" %(os.getpid())
```

When I execute invoke.py from shell it returns immediately and longtime.py works in background (works on Windows and Linux). If I call invoke.py through Web Interface (Apache CGI) it works under Linux **but not on Windows** machine, there the website gets stuck and only returns after longtime.py has finished.

How can I configure Python subprocess or Apache to get the same behavior under Windows? Whats the difference?

Maybe the Apache config on Windows is somehow different but i didnt find something.

Linux: Debian, Python2.5.2, Apache2.2.9
Windows: WinXP, Python2.7, Apache2.2.17

Maybe you have also a better design approach (because its a little awkward how I do it now).

What for?: I have a script on the webserver which takes quite a long time to calculate (longtime.py). I want to activate the execution via web interface. The Website should return immediatly and longtime.py should work in background and writes output in a file. Later a request from web interface checks if the file is generated and reads the output. I can not use common cloud-provider as they dont support multithreading. Also I can not install a daemon handler on the webserver because processes have a maximum runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the code below on Windows XP and on OSX 10.6.6 (shell) and it exits without waiting for the child process to finish.

**invoke.py:**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import platform


if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    close_fds=False
else: 
    close_fds=True

p = Popen('python long.py', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=close_fds, shell=True)
print "Content-Type: text/plain\n"
print "invoked (%d)" % (p.pid)
```

**long.py**

```
import time
import os
print "start (%d)" %(os.getpid())
time.sleep(10)
print "end (%d)" %(os.getpid())
```

**Update:**
Tested on Windows 7 + Apache 2.2.17 + Python 2.7 + mod_wsgi 3.3.

mod_wsgi.so file can be downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DownloadTheSoftware?tm=2).
File should be renamed to mod_wsgi.so and and placed in apache modules folder.

**invoke.wsgi:**
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import platform

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        close_fds=False
    else: 
        close_fds=True

    p = Popen('python "C:\testing\long.py"', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=close_fds, shell=True)

    status = '200 OK'
    output = "invoked (%d)" % (p.pid)    
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

**long.py** file was left unchanged.

changes made to **httpd.conf**:

append wsgi module:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

add directory to the config

```
<Directory "C:/testing">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

link url with directory

```
Alias /testapp "C:\testing"
```

link url with wsgi app

```
WSGIScriptAlias /testapp "C:\testing\invoke.wsgi"
```

Restart web server.
Go http://server_name/testapp 
App should show process id and exit.

Comment: Hi tuscias, Ive tested it with your code and it works in shell (as the previous version too) but not if I call the invoke.py from webpage and let Apache execute it. I also played around with the parameters to Popen but always the same result. I think the problem is the Apache, can't figure out why. Did it work for you with Apache or just with shell?

Comment: I appended another solution with mod_wsgi. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing out WSGI. I modified my structure of calling services and it works nice with WSGI!!!